# Zip all the files in a directory(not the directory) using php

Tags: php, zip

```
$fileToZip="License.txt";
$fileToZip1="CreateZipFileMac.inc.php";
$fileToZip2="CreateZipFile.inc.php";

$directoryToZip="../images"; // This will zip all the file(s) in this present working directory

$outputDir="/"; //Replace "/" with the name of the desired output directory.
$zipName="test.zip";

include_once("CreateZipFile.inc.php");
$createZipFile=new CreateZipFile;


//Code toZip a directory and all its files/subdirectories
$createZipFile->zipDirectory($directoryToZip,$outputDir);

$rand=md5(microtime().rand(0,999999));
$zipName=$rand."_".$zipName;
$fd=fopen($zipName, "wb");
$out=fwrite($fd,$createZipFile->getZippedfile());
fclose($fd);
$createZipFile->forceDownload($zipName);
@unlink($zipName); `
```

When I run this code, it creates a zip file `test.zip` but when I extract it, I'll get all the files inside the `images` folder and I don't want that to happen. I just want to get all the files, not in a folder, when extracting. How can I modify this code in order to achieve it? Is there any other way to do that? Thank you.

Comment: All the "magic" that adds the files is in your CreateZipFile class, specifically the zipDirectory() method.... butyou appear to have forgotten to post this.

Comment: I didn't write that function, I just used this class "CreateZipFile.inc.php" (http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/9524.html). But i found the solution to my problem. Use 'ZipArchive' class and replace '$zip->addFile($file,$file);' with this one '$zip->addFile($file,pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_BASENAME));'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-addfile.php#93090) is what you're looking for.
You should be able to gut that and modify it as needed.  It depends on the [ZipArchive](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class.

Comment: yup, thanks...it works fine when i replace '$zip->addFile($file,$file);' with this one '$zip->addFile($file,pathinfo($file,PATHINFO_BASENAME));'

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but have you tried changing this:

```
$directoryToZip="../images";
```

to this:

```
$directoryToZip="../images/";
```